# Testcafe TypeText function not working with CKeditor

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have targeted the following element to enter text into the wysiwyg editor:

```
<div class="ck ck-content ck-editor__editable ck-rounded-corners ck-editor__editable_inline ck-blurred" lang="en" dir="ltr" role="textbox" aria-label="Editor editing area: main" contenteditable="true"><p><br data-cke-filler="true"></p></div>
```

For some reason it seems that the typeText function does not want to enter text in the text box

After trying the following. I can see  testcafe is clicking into the textbox but not typing any characters:

```
const editable = Selector('.ckeditor__editable[contenteditable=true')
await t.click(editable).typeText(editable, 'test')
```

Comment: Hi, I reproduced the issue and created a separate report regarding it: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/7642. We will research it in detail.

Comment: Thanks, any suggested work around would also be welcome

Comment: Hi, You can try using the workaround shared by "aorioir" in the bug report I created.

Comment: Hi the work around worked thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that comes across the issue there is a bug raised [here](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/7642)

Meanwhile the current work around as stated in the issue that worked for me is as follows:

```
await t.eval(() => {
   const editor = window.document.querySelector(".ck-editor__editable");
   editor.ckeditorInstance.data.set(whateverYouWant);
},
{ 
   dependencies: { whateverYouWant } 
});
```